# Error while restarting Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I tried to restart MongoDB on my server, but I got an error. The error log:

```
2018-05-24T12:22:08.308+0200 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2018-05-24T12:22:08.422+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=13662 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=Challenger
2018-05-24T12:22:08.422+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.5
2018-05-24T12:22:08.422+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a20ecd3e3a174162052ff99913bc2ca9a839d618
2018-05-24T12:22:08.422+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2018-05-24T12:22:08.422+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-05-24T12:22:08.422+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-05-24T12:22:08.422+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-05-24T12:22:08.422+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2018-05-24T12:22:08.422+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-05-24T12:22:08.422+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-05-24T12:22:08.422+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { timeZoneInfo: "/usr/share/zoneinfo" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb",$
2018-05-24T12:22:08.424+0200 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2018-05-24T12:22:08.424+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
2018-05-24T12:22:08.424+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2018-05-24T12:22:08.424+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2018-05-24T12:22:08.424+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=256M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),cache_cursors=false,log=(enabled=true,ar$
2018-05-24T12:22:09.379+0200 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1527157329:379309][13662:0x7f6ea10839c0], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: /var/lib/mongodb/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
2018-05-24T12:22:09.380+0200 E -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:1: Operation not permitted src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 416
2018-05-24T12:22:09.402+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: Location28595: 1: Operation not permitted, terminating
2018-05-24T12:22:09.402+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2018-05-24T12:22:09.402+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2018-05-24T12:22:09.402+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-05-24T12:22:09.402+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

can anyone tell me what the bug is?

Comment: have you started mongod service ?

Comment: That's the problem. I can't start mongod, because I get the error.

Comment: `sudo service mongod start`???

Comment: Yes. I used command 'sudo service mongod start' and then 'sudo service mongod status'. and it sais: failed to start. So I opened /var/log/mongodb.log and I got that error. Probably there is something wrong with the collections in /var/lib/mongodb because if I change the dbpath to an empty directory, everything is fine. However I need those data... Is there any possible way to recover data from the '/var/lib/mongodb'?

Comment: stop your mongodb service and then follow these steps https://askubuntu.com/questions/884541/cant-start-mongodb-service

Comment: It's not working. It's just delete the data folder and reinstall the mongodb. It works well, but when I move my data back to /var/lib/mongodb, I get the same error. So, the problem is not with the mongodb but with the data in it....